# reference to pointer to int causes error

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, int

I have the following piece of code, which is an implementation of an array resizing function. It seems to be correct, but when I compile the program I get the following errors:

```
g++ -Wall -o "resizing_arrays" "resizing_arrays.cpp" (in directory: /home/aristofanis/Desktop/coursera-impl)
resizing_arrays.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
resizing_arrays.cpp:37: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int*&’ from a temporary of type ‘int*’
resizing_arrays.cpp:7: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void resize(int*&, int, int, int)’
resizing_arrays.cpp:39: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int*&’ from a temporary of type ‘int*’
resizing_arrays.cpp:7: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void resize(int*&, int, int, int)’
resizing_arrays.cpp:41: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int*&’ from a temporary of type ‘int*’
resizing_arrays.cpp:7: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void resize(int*&, int, int, int)’
Compilation failed.
```

Here is the code:

```
int N=5;

void resize( int *&arr, int N, int newCap, int initial=0 ) { // line 7
  N = newCap;
  int *tmp = new int[ newCap ];
  for( int i=0; i<N; ++i ) {
    tmp[ i ] = arr[ i ];
  }
  if( newCap > N ) {
    for( int i=N; i<newCap; ++i ) {
      tmp[ i ] = initial;
    }
  }

  arr = new int[ newCap ];

  for( int i=0; i<newCap; ++i ) {
    arr[ i ] = tmp[ i ];
  }
}

void print( int *arr, int N ) {
  for( int i=0; i<N; ++i ) {
    cout << arr[ i ];
    if( i != N-1 ) cout << " ";
  }
}

int main() {
  int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

  print( arr, N );
  resize( arr, N, 5, 6 ); // line 37
  print( arr, N);
  resize( arr, N, 10, 1 ); // line 39
  print( arr, N );
  resize( arr, N, 3 ); // line 41
  print ( arr, N );

  return 0;
}
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `void resize( int *&arr` here remove the `&`

Comment: @IonutHulub - that would defeat the purpose of the function, which is to change the size of the array that the pointer argument points to.

Comment: there is no such thing as a `*&arr`. what data type do you think that is? arr is a pointer so you can't call & on it, and even if you could, * undos the effect of & cause one is for reference and one if for dereference.

Comment: @IonutHulub actually there is. It is a reference to a pointer to an int and it allows you to make changes both to the pointer and to the value that it points to.

Comment: never heard of that. I'll check it.

Comment: Here it is again: "ARRAYS ARE NOT POINTERS IN C++".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `main`, you declare

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

an ordinary array, not an `int*`, which is what you would have to pass to `resize`.

And, although that is not technically necessary for your implementation of `resize`, since you never `delete[]` any allocated memory there - a space leak you should fix -, the pointer you pass to `resize` should point to a `new`-allocated memory block (that you should `delete[]` in `resize`).

Comment: it is impossible to resize a static array, so this isn't _quite_ the right advice, though you did identify the problem.

Comment: As is, passing any `int*` to `resize` will leak-but-work, `resize` will make it point to a different location (losing the possibly last reference to the old block).

Answer (score 7):

`arr` is an array that's allocated on the stack. You can't change its size. If you need a resizable array, use a pointer and allocate the array with `new`.

Answer (score 1):

An array is **not** a pointer. In particular, an array stays put. You cannot move it. In the context you are using the poibters you would also create memory leaks and out of bound accesses.

To create a resizable array, you will need to maintain a pointer which gets initially set up from a copy of the elements in you array. Personally, I wouldn't bother and use `std::vector<int>` (unless I'm working on my own standard C++ library and implement `std::vector<T>`).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the specific error you're getting is that `arr` will decay to a temporary `int*` as used. You then try and bind a non-const reference (the parameter) to the temporary, which is illegal. See here:

[How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Answer (score 0):

When you say `int&` it means that an `int` variable that I can change its value, similarly when you say `int*&`, it means an `int*` variable that I can change its value. now look at your code can you change the value of `arr`. is it legal to say `arr = new int[10]`? you see it is not legal, in C++ term it is not an `Lvalue`(it can't sit in left side of equal operator) and all non-const references must be `Lvalue`

Comment: both `arr` and `new int[10]` can be on the right side of an equal operator, and all mutable references must be _lvalues_.

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks for your comment, it was a simple mistake!! I mean lvalue too. thanks again